# Typescript: How can I define a generic function with a specific first parameter without losing function types?

Tags: typescript

I am defining a higher-order function that accepts a of functions to be transformed into functions with one fewer parameter (because I'll be passing in a value for the first parameter). I need the following constraints:

- The caller of the function MUST pass in an object whose properties are all functions that take in a number as their first parameter (any other parameters can be anything, return type can be anything)
- Users of the output are required to call each function using parameters matching the caller's function signatures (but without that first parameter)

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Aclass%20MyFns%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a(one%3A%20number%2C%20s%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20one%20%2B%20s.length%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b(one%3A%20number%2C%20n%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20one%20%2B%20n%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ExpectedOutFns%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a(s%3A%20string)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b(n%3A%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20passTwo(mapOfFns)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20transformedMap%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20k%20in%20mapOfFns)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fany%5B%5D%20is%20wrong%20here%20-%20not%20exact%20enough%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20can%20I%20somehow%20type%20this%20based%20on%20mapOfFns%5Bk%5D%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transformedMap%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20mapOfFns%5Bk%5D(2%2C%20...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20transformedMap%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20out%3A%20ExpectedOutFns%20%3D%20passTwo(new%20MyFns())%3B)

```
class MyFns {
    a(one: number, s: string) {
        return one + s.length;
    }
    b(one: number, n: number, m: number) {
        return one + n + m;
    }
}

interface ExpectedOutFns {
    a(s: string): number;
    b(n: number, m: number): number;
}

function passOne(mapOfFns) {
    const transformedMap = {};
    for (const k in mapOfFns) {
        //any[] is wrong here - not exact enough
        // can I somehow type this based on mapOfFns[k]?
        transformedMap[k] = (...args: any[]) => mapOfFns[k](1, ...args);
    }
    return transformedMap;
}

const out: ExpectedOutFns = passOne(new MyFns()); // Error
```

This gives me the following error:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ExpectedOutFns'.
>     Property 'a' is missing in type '{}'.

I've also tried [explicitly typing everything](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20FnMap%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(one%3A%20number%2C%20...rest%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TransformedFnMap%3CFnMap%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BKey%20in%20keyof%20FnMap%5D%3A%20FnMap%5BKey%5D%20%2F%2F%20TODO%3A%20without%20the%20first%20param%3F%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyFns%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(one%3A%20number%2C%20...rest%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a(one%3A%20number%2C%20s%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20one%20%2B%20s.length%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b(one%3A%20number%2C%20n%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20one%20%2B%20n%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ExpectedOutFns%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a(s%3A%20string)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b(n%3A%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20passOne%3CT%20extends%20FnMap%3E(mapOfFunctions%3A%20T)%3A%20TransformedFnMap%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20transformedMap%3A%20FnMap%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20k%20in%20mapOfFunctions)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20transformedMap%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20mapOfFunctions%5Bk%5D(1%2C%20...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(%3CTransformedFnMap%3CT%3E%3EtransformedMap)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20out%20%3A%20ExpectedOutFns%20%3D%20passOne(new%20MyFns())%3B) but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think it's possible until the next version (3.0) of TypeScript which includes [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) is released

Comment: Ah thank you so much! The "generic rest parameters" looks like exactly what I needed.